# Any drawback to naming a Rails app "App"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Seems every rails project I do, I'm not satisfied with the initial name that it's given. Either the project name ends up changing, or it's just generally useless to have that proper noun in my code. It's not like I'm running multiple rails apps in the same runtime.

One solution that appeals to me is to name the app "App" -- are there any drawbacks to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that i know of, the only one i see is that if you have multiple projects named app, and you need to be a specific one, it can be time consuming

Comment: What do you mean "need to be a specific one" -- and please elaborate on this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: if you have 10 projects named app. if you need to find a specific one within them you wont be able to find it by name..

Comment: what do you mean "find"? like, within my file browser? the top level directories would still have relevant names...

Comment: oh ok, the no problem that i know of